# IBM.EntityFrameworkCore Error - [42815] [IBM][AS] SQL0451N

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, db2, db2-400

I am getting the error below when trying to run a stored procedure using IBM.EntityFrameworkCore against a Db2 database:

```
IBM.Data.Db2.DB2Exception (0x80004005): ERROR [42815] [IBM][AS] SQL0451N  
The "1" definition, in the statement that defines routine "*N        ", 
contains a data type "FOOSCHEMA.FOONAME" that is not appropriate for a non-sourced routine 
written in the given language or a routine that is defined as autonomous.
   at IBM.Data.Db2.DB2Connection.HandleError(IntPtr hHandle, SQL_HANDLE hType, RETCODE retcode)
   at IBM.Data.Db2.DB2Command.ExecuteNonQueryObject(Boolean skipInitialValidation)
   at IBM.Data.Db2.DB2Command.ExecuteNonQueryObject()
   at IBM.Data.Db2.DB2Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

My logic is below

```cs
using var db2 = await db2Context.CreateDbContextAsync();
using var command = db2.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();

command.CommandText = "call FOOSCHEMA.FOONAME(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

command.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter
{
    ParameterName = "FooInputParam",
    Value = "ST",
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
    DB2Type = DB2Type.Char,
    Size = 2,
});

command.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter
{
    ParameterName = "FooInputOutputParam",
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput,
    DB2Type = DB2Type.Char,
    Size = 500
});

/* 3 additional `Input` params redacted */

await db2.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();
var commandResult = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); // ERROR HERE
```

I did some searching but came up empty on things to try. I *am* able to successfully call other stored procedures in Db2 using IBM.EntityFrameworkCore in my environment.

Below is the program signature

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas of what I need to look at to resolve?

---

Environment Details

- .NET 8 application

  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.2
  - IBM.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.0.200
- Db2 for i

  - 7.4
  - Level 26

Comment: A similar issue was reported [here](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datamanagement/discussion/ibmdatadb2core-sql0451n-calling-program-error) back in 2021.

Comment: @mao I have added some environment details. Let me know if there is a something else that would help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you done any investigations? What is the signature (i.e the `create procedure` ddl ) for the stored-procedure? Does the symptom happen for *every* stored-procedure?  Does the symptom change if the procedure is not autonomous, or has no pararameters, or if the stored-procedure is written in a different programming language?

Comment: @mao I have edited the question to include the program signature. I am able to successfully call other Db2 programs using IBM.EntityFrameworkCore in my app. I have limited access/knowledge to the Db2 database so I'm not entirely sure what autonomous procedures are, but I will try to find out. Thanks.

Comment: Also of note, in our Db2 environment, some programs are ILE, and some are CL compiled. I'm not sure if that affects anything.

Comment: @mao can you point me to documentation to determine the autonomous setting?

Comment: You have a "working" and a "failing" stored-procedure. Something about the failing routine, or how it it is built or how it gets invoked  (e.g parameter data type mappings, or other parameter characteristic) or how it is configured is amiss. Compare qsys2.sysroutines columns for working and failing routines, eliminate each difference. The autonomous flag is the commit_on_return column value AUT but that may be a red herring, as I'm only working back from the SQL0451N message text. Study the SQL0451 section of the docs here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=codes-listing-sql-messages.

Comment: @mao I received info from my Db2 admin that the routine that is *not* working is not in `QSYS2.SYSROUTINES`. However, we are able to call these routines successfully from existing/older applications using System.Data.OleDb. Maybe something has changed from the older OleDb adapter to the newer EF Core adapter that doesn't allow this to work anymore?

Comment: The other interesting thing is that the older calls are wrapping the command in curly braces...something like `"{{call SCHEMA.ROUTINE(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}}"`. However, when I try that, I receive the following message: `ERROR [42601] [IBM][AS] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "{" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "( CL END GET SET TAG CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER".`

Comment: Is the target program in any of the catalog views/tables? (e.g.sysprocs, sysprogramstat, sysparms etc) If not, it should be possible to build the program so that it is catalogued. Another approach is to trace the driver, and compare the trace-output for a working stored-procedure with that of calling an uncatalogued procedure. Only IBM can state whether the driver supports uncatalogued procedures on the i-series, so you should open a ticket with IBM to get that answered. In the meanwhile, see if you can get the DBA to make a catalogued version of the program to compare the behaviour.

Comment: @mao can you link to documentation that describes how to build a program so that it is catalogued?

Comment: Did you open a ticket with IBM-i support? Did you trace the driver? Refer to the i-knowledge centre for details of the variations of the `create procedure` statement (which will catalog a procedure) , for example https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-create-procedure-external  (and all related and linked pages, many exist).

Comment: `IBM Ticket` - I'm in the process of requesting access to open a case on the IBM site. | `CREATE PROCEDURE` - We have verified that using `CREATE PROCEDURE` does work. When we use this, the calls that previously failed using `IBM.EntityFrameworkCore` succeed. The question is if it's possible to make calls against programs that don't have this as we have in the past with other providers | `Trace Driver` - I'm not familiar with this. Could you point me to some docs that explain how to do this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a process of elimination, the **workaround** is to ensure that the routine being called is catalogued. in other words the target routine appears in the database catalog (in your case, in `qsys2.routines` and all related tables for arguments etc.). To catalog a procedure, use the `create procedure` statement, and when the target procedure is external to the RDBMS, use a specific flavour of that statement as described in the docs [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-create-procedure-external) (be sure to read all the related pages, there are many).

Only IBM can state whether this is a **feature** or a **defect** (and if so, in which exact component, it might not be their entity framework support alone) '. So you should open a ticket IBM i-support to get an answer, although you might need to be persistent. You could then update this answer. IBM may also suggest other different workarounds.

I do know that in the past with the Db2-LUW product (i.e. not i-series) it was possible to invoke uncatalogued external procedures, but that some decades ago IBM made this practice either more difficult or restricted . I never use uncatalogued routines now since recent decades, regardless of the scaffolding/interface.

For tracing the driver, again refer to IBM, as the tracing details will vary with the driver. That is not a programming matter but a documentation matter, but IBM software is usually able to be traced at runtime for the purposes of problem determination. Their support for the MS Entity Framework seems to be very much an add on ,with minimal documentation, but I believe will still be traceable.

Comment: I received a reply from IBM support: `Db2 Connect .NET Providers (ADO .NET and EF) Framework as well as Core versions don't support any such calling conventions/methods, moreover, we don't have any validations with CL programs in our test infra. In short, it's not supported and validated. The customer may open an AHA request to expedite it.`